# Send continues data to client through websocket

Tags: java, websocket

I have a requirement to send the huge data through the websockets. My actual requirement is, the client communicates with my server for huge test data. My server will send the data assume the data size is 1GB. Its very hard to send this 1GB of data in a single response. So I choose the websockets. I am very new to this topic. I read about the websocets in multiple blogs and everyone gave a chat application example. But in my case client will ask once and my server needs to send the continues data. Is it possible to send the continues test data to the client with the websocets.? Can any one help me on this and if possible can you please provide an example.?

Note: I am using JAVA.

Thanks & Regards,
Amar.T

Comment: WebSocket is a full duplex connection from any two clients over TCP. Depending upon what kind of a client you have, you can send the data accordingly. In case of 1GB data, split it into chunks and then send. For data integrity you can also do checksums.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the chat example. Use it. Try it on single computer. Probably you will need to create own protocol for sending/receiving data. Try to send by limited sizes blocks (for example 10 kb). So you will have 2 applications: client and server used websockets. I think that the main problem here is - What to do if connection was lost?